# What is the type and name of this 15-pin connector pair?

Tags: connector, identification, cables, pins, panel

This connector is suited on a Sony car stereo front panel. Searched the net however could not find anything. I love to extend the connection with a sort of cable so it possible to fit the front panel somewhere else.

- What is the type of the connector?
- What is the name of the connector?

[image: 15-pin connector]

Comment: If you desolder one, usually there is a manufacturer name, code, or symbol on it somewhere.

Comment: How the contact spacing can be different between the male and female parts?

Comment: @dim I think that's spacing as in gap between rather than distance between centres or pitch.

Comment: @dim As showed on the picture, the pins are not straight, the actual point of connection is actually smaller. That's why there is a difference in size.

Comment: @Codebeat Yes, but the sum of contact/pin size + contact/pin spacing should be the same for both, if I understand correctly. And it isn't the case here (2.7mm vs 2.3mm). In any case, what is more relevant than this is the *pitch*. Please measure it precisely: take the distance between the centerline of the leftmost pin and the centerline of the rightmost pin, and divide by the number of spaces (instead of measuring from centerline, it may be easier to use the left, or right end of both pins: just use a consistent reference point). I bet it is 2.54mm, but having it confirmed would be nice.

Comment: I am also looking for the same.
Please let me know if you could solve this problem or not yet, because I am still looking where to buy this part.
Thank you

Comment: @Eng.M.IyadKhoudary Your best chance of getting one of those connectors might be to buy a unit with that connector and desolder it.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same but male connector on my Mazda 6 stereo. It is very difficult to find this type of connector. I found only the connection diagram which says that this is type CN703 connector but I can't find where to buy by this designation.

[image: CN703 male]

[image: diagram]

Comment: Crutchfield has lots of converting harnesses; maybe with this info you can find something there.

Comment: CN703 is the reference number of the connector on the PCB and can be found as CN703 in the schematic. This is not the type of connector.